# Is std::iterator inherints from a sort of auto_ptr?

Tags: c++, stl

I am a beginner in STL. I'm trying to code a toystl to learn STL. When I code about iterator, I'm puzzled if I should code a simple auto_ptr first and inherint from it.

I wrote a base class called iterator. And now it works like this,

```
struct iterator{};

template <class T>
struct vector_itorater: public toystl::iterator<toystl::random_access_iterator_tag, T>{};
```

If i need another base class works like a "auto_ptr"? just like this

```
// firstly define a sort of auto_ptr as base class
struct auto_ptr{};

// secondly inherint from auto_ptr
template <class T>
struct vector_itorater: public auto_ptr{};
```

Does this work? Or does STL do it like this?

Comment: Just look at the source code for auto_ptr if you want to know how it's implemented. However, auto_ptr has some serious issues and you should use shared_ptr or unique_ptr with a more modern c++. Especially  as you are in the learning mode. Best to learn with the most current c++ together with a current book.

Comment: Why would a vector's iterator inherit from `auto_ptr`?  None of the standard containers' iterators have any sort of ownership over the data they reference.  `auto_ptr` is also deprecated and removed in C++17, so even if iterators _did_ own data, `auto_ptr` would be a poor choice.

Comment: typically, iterators only need a little data. For example, you can implement a vector iterator with just a pointer. Because of this, iterators are typically copyable structs passed around by value, so no memory management is needed in the class itself.

Comment: @doug Thanks, I got it. I am reading the book <More Effective C++> by Soctt Meyers.

Comment: @Miles Budnek I originally wanted to reuse operations such as "*", "->" and "++". It seems that this cannot be done

Comment: @ parktomatomi That's it, I get it !

Comment: @monkystars In that case it could make sense to have both `auto_ptr` and `vector<T>::iterator` derive from some `pointer_wrapper` class.  It doesn't really make sense for one to derive from the other though.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mixed up runtime polymorphy and compile time polymorphy. When the compiler instantiates a template, it cares about its visible interface of the concrete object. It does not care if this object has a inheritance relationship with other classes, it will pass as long as the concrete object can be used within the concrete context.

```
template <class C>
void foo(const C& bar)
{
    // at the time of writing we don't know anything of C,
    // only that it has a callable baz member (either a
    // member function or a member with a call operator).
    // This works, since the compiler knows the exact type
    // during template instantiation, but we don't have to
    // care in advance.
    bar.baz();
}

struct X
{
    void baz() const;
};

void grml()
{
    X x;
    // The compiler fills in X as the template type
    // parameter for us. So the compiler creates a
    // void foo<X>(const X&) function for us.
    foo(x);
}
```

In this example when the compiler sees the template, it has no clue how this template will be called later. Only once the template gets instantiated (used), the compiler then will check if the passed type is suitable for this template.

Here it is not needed to have a common base class to derive every possible implementation from. The STL uses templates in order to avoid to use such base classes, since they give you a burden on your design later, and if you have virtual members in the base to override, you can get a serious performance penalty.

Comment: Thanks, template is really powerful!